# It is possible to create albums in groups using graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I'm writing web app for Facebook. I can successfully create albums for users and pages, and upload images to them. But I still can't create albums in groups. Even in the graph explorer with all permissions ON, on the request

POST /[group num]/albums with POST field name=[somename]

I receive error

> (#10) Application does not have permission for this action

Tell me please, it is really possible to create albums in groups via API? Or it is a known bug?

Comment: You may report feature request at https://www.facebook.com/help/suggestions to create a group album using Graph API, but it's funny i found a bug report created on 01/01/1970 7:00am at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/151879304936505/